# Is Zeus ever referred to as Earthshaker?

Tags: zeus, olympians, poseidon

From my exposure to Greek mythology (*[The Iliad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad)*, *[The Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey)*, etc.) I had always seen/heard the god of the sea, [Poseidon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poseidon), referred to as Earth-Shaker. [Zeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus) was always given other titles such as Zeus Cloud-Gatherer or Zeus Thunderer.

However, in the book *[Moses and Monotheism](https://ia600500.us.archive.org/15/items/mosesandmonothei032233mbp/mosesandmonothei032233mbp.pdf)* (p. 74), [Sigmund Freud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmund_Freud) writes:

> Zeus still bears the name of "the Earth-shaker."

This seems incorrect to me, as Earth-Shaker seems to be Poseidon's title, not Zeus's title.

A preliminary google search did not return any results for Zeus being referred to as Earth-Shaker. So did Freud simply make a mistake, and use Poseidon's title for Zeus, or are there actually instances where Zeus is referred to as Earth-Shaker?

Answer (score 10):

In later (hellenistic) times Zeus tended to monopolize all powers and earthquakes came to be his deed. There is a classic book by AB Cook [Zeus: a study in ancient religion](https://archive.org/download/Zeus.StudyInAncientReligion.Vol.3PartIIizeusGodOfTheDarkSky/CookArthurBernard-Zeus.StudyInAncientReligion.Vol.3PartIIi.pdf), part3 has some 30 pages on "Zeus and eartquakes",  eg. p.21:

> The same feeling that the failure of the solid ground can be ascribed
>   to no power lower than the highest prompts the Orphic hymn-writer
>   boldly to transfer the epithet seisickthon,' who maketh the land to
>   quake/ from Poseidon5 to Zeus6 and the author of a Sibylline oracle to
>   use the like language of his supreme Deity7. The fact is that, as the
>   centuries went by, Poseidon lost while Zeus gained in religious
>   significance. Earthquakes came to be connected less and less with the
>   former, more and more with the latter.

Answer (score 7):

In the same chapter "Zeus and the Earthquakes" of *[Zeus: a study in ancient religion](https://archive.org/stream/zeusstudyinancie03cook#page/n33/mode/2up)*, Vol. III, by [Arthur Bernard Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Bernard_Cook), quoted by @sand1 in his answer, the author says:

> In point of fact, the earliest extant description of an earthquake 
>   attributes the phenomenon, naively enough, to the action of Zeus,  who
>   nods his head, shakes his hair, and thereby makes the mighty  mass of
>   Mount Olympos to tremble.

Indeed, Homer in the *Iliad* tells us this about Zeus:

> The son of Cronos spoke, and bowed his dark brow in assent, and the
>   ambrosial locks waved from the king's immortal head; and he made great
>   Olympus quake.

[<sup>Homer, *Iliad*. 1.528</sup>](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134%3Abook%3D1%3Acard%3D493)

But, as you already mention in your question, Poseidon is called "Shaker of Earth" more than [thirty times](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=en&all_words=shaker&phrase=&any_words=&exclude_words=&documents=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134) in the same work.

I wouldn't discard an earlier association between earthquakes and a [chthonic Zeus](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/400/which-cities-had-chthonic-zeus-cults) but, during the classic period at least, "the Shaker of Earth" was definitively Poseidon.

Then, as @sand1 mentions in his answer, and quoting again from *Zeus, a study in religion*:

> The fact is that, as the centuries went by, Poseidon lost while Zeus
>   gained in religious significance. Earthquakes came to be connected
>   less and less with the former, more and more with the latter.

The author then mentions a series of earthquakes, with the first examples attributed to Zeus dating from A.D. times.